# Systemwise `node_modules` and `bower_components`

Tags: node.js, bower

How to have shared `node_modules` and `bower_components` across all projects in `Windows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround by creating directory link to shared folder using `mklink /J node_modules C:\node_modules` inside each project. This way all node_modules folders in projects will point to **C:\node_modules**. Only precaution here is not to use `-purge` option with npm and bower.